# Unable to access console or SSH on Amazon Linux 2 KVM image

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virsh, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to create a KVM guest instance running Amazon Linux 2 in an on-premises environment, on a CentOS 7 host. I am doing this over SSH (e.g. my local machine -> SSH to the CentOS host).

I know my hypervisor setup works, as using the following commands, I can create a CentOS 7 guest with SSH access no problem at all:

```
OS_IMG=CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2
DIR=/home/libvirt
SCRIPTS=$DIR/scripts
BOOT=$DIR/boot
IMG=$DIR/images
VM=centos-vm-test

# +++ Downloading image OS image
cd $BOOT
wget http://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/$OS_IMG

# +++ Creating meta/user data
cd $IMG/$VM
echo -e "instance-id: $VM\nlocal-hostname: $VM" > meta-data
cp $SCRIPTS/user-data user-data
cp $BOOT/$OS_IMG $VM.qcow2

# +++ Creating disk
export LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata $VM.new.image 40G
virt-resize --quiet --expand /dev/sda1 $VM.qcow2 $VM.new.image
mv $VM.new.image $VM.qcow2

# +++ Creating CD-ROM containing cloud init data
mkisofs -o $VM-cidata.iso -V cidata -J -r user-data meta-data

# +++ Creating VM"
virt-install --import --name $VM \
    --memory 4096 --vcpus 2 --cpu host \
    --disk $VM.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio \
    --disk $VM-cidata.iso,device=cdrom \
    --network bridge=virbr0,model=virtio \
    --os-type=linux \
    --os-variant=centos7.0 \
    --noautoconsole
```

Within seconds, I can run `virsh net-dhcp-leases` and see an IP address which I can SSH to.

I have tried to replicate this process with Amazon Linux 2, using the image found here: https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/os-images/2.0.20200304.0/kvm/

For `user-data`, I have tried my CentOS file (quite lengthy, including a lot of `runcmd` lines) and the recommended basic contents found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-2-virtual-machine.html. I don't see any difference when using the 2 different files.

This doesn't appear to work however, and I'm stuck as to how I can proceed further.

- I am unable to run `virsh console myvmname`, as it just gets stuck on `Escape character is ^]` (return key does nothing). On the CentOS guest, I can run `virsh console myvmname` and with a single hit of the return key, I'm connected as expected
- If I run `virsh net-dhcp-leases default`, there are no leases - so I don't have an IP address that I can attempt SSH connection on
- Logs in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu` show nothing wrong; the failed AL2 logs look identical to the working CentOS guests' logs.

I have also tried to copy the process *exactly* as recommended on the previous Amazon link, including using `genisoimage` with the `seed.iso` file etc. but this appears to make no difference.

How can I get access to this VM, or at least attempt to work out what's going wrong? Boot logs would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across the fix here: https://github.com/giovtorres/kvm-install-vm/blob/master/kvm-install-vm#L630

Basically, I needed to use `qemu-img resize` rather than `qemu-img create`:

```
if [[ $al2 == "Y" ]]; then
    qemu-img resize $VM.qcow2 40G &>> ${VM}.log

    echo "+++ Creating CD-ROM containing cloud init data"
    genisoimage -output $VM-cidata.iso \
                -volid cidata \
                -joliet -r user-data meta-data &>> ${VM}.log
else
    export LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct
    qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=metadata $VM.new.image 40G
    virt-resize --quiet --expand /dev/sda1 $VM.qcow2 $VM.new.image
    mv $VM.new.image $VM.qcow2

    echo "+++ Creating CD-ROM containing cloud init data"
    mkisofs -o $VM-cidata.iso -V cidata -J -r user-data meta-data
fi
```